# Display hyperlinks in a jTextArea

Tags: java, hyperlink

I did a search engine where I can enter some words and find the links where this words appears. But when I display this links, I am displaying it as string, and I want to display it as hyperlinks, that the user can click and connect to the site. I used the solutions I found here on stackoverflow, but none of then worked.

Does anyone knows how can I do it? At the moment, I am displaying the results inside a jTextArea.

Comment: A code showing how exactly are you displaying the links will be helpful so someone could spot the mistake, hence give you an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am displaying the results inside a jTextArea

You can't use a JTextArea. A JTextArea only displays simple text.

You need to display HTML in a `JEditorPane` and add the links using HTML. Then you add a `HyperLinkListener` to the editor pane.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Editor Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for general information and examples.

Read the `JEditorPane` API for an example on how to create a `HyperLinkListener` and respond to mouse clicks.